# How to draw a radial dot image depending on data label in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to draw a image like that, which according to the data predicted label
[image]

For instance, there are five samples [A,B,C,D,E]
and their label like [0,0,0,1,1]
Is there some existed package can be used in python?

Besides, I want to add color according samples' rgb coordinate, can this package finish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with networkx and matplotlib.
Here a minimal example:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


group_a = "group_a"
group_b = "group_b"

data = list("ABCDE")
labels = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]

# create an empty graph
G = nx.Graph()

G.add_node(group_a)
G.add_node(group_b)

# add one group or another depending on the label
for i, label in zip(data, labels):
    if not label:
        target = group_a
    else: 
        target = group_b
        
    G.add_edge(i, target)


nx.draw_networkx(G)
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following image:

[image: Example_picture]

For more info see the  [Networkx doc](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html).

Comment: How to add color in each node?